# I cant display the image from my database

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Im trying to create an online shopping system which will display and add a product with image. Ive watched and follow a video tutorial but I cant seem to display the image from my database.

index file

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblproducts ORDER BY placeOrder DESC";
$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt , $sql)) {
  echo "SQL statement failed!";
} else {
  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

    echo"
   <div><img src='".$row['image']."' uploads/></div>
    <h3>".$row["imageTitle"]."</h3>
    <p>".$row["prod_description"]."</p>";

  }
}
```

upload file

```
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $newFileName = $_POST['filename'];
    if (empty($newFileName)) {
    $newFileName = "tblproducts";
    } else {
    $newFileName = strtolower(str_replace(" ","-", $newFileName));
    }
    $imageTitle = $_POST['filetitle'];
    $imageDesc = $_POST['filedesc'];

    $file = $_FILES['file'];

    $fileName = $file["name"];
      $fileType = $file["type"];
      $fileTempName = $file["tmp_name"];
      $fileError = $file["error"];
      $fileSize = $file["size"];

  $fileExt = explode(".", $fileName);
  $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

  $allowed = array("jpg", "jpeg", "png");

  if (in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)) {
    if ($fileError === 0) {
      if ($fileSize < 2000000) {
      $imageFullName = $newFileName . "." . uniqid("", true) . "." . $fileActualExt;
      $fileDestination = "uploads/" . $imageFullName;


        include_once "conn.php";

        if (empty($imageTitle) || empty($imageDesc)) {
        header("Location: ../index.one.php?upload=empty");
        exit();
      }else{
          $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblproducts;";
          $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
          if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
            echo "SQL statement failed! ";
          } else {
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
            $rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
            $setImageOrder = $rowCount + 1;

            $sql = "INSERT INTO tblproducts (imageTitle, prod_description, image, placeOrder) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);";
            if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
              echo "SQL statement failed! ";
            } else {
              mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss",$imageTitle, $imageDesc, $imageFullName, $setImageOrder);
              mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

              move_uploaded_file($fileTempName, $fileDestination);

            header('location:index.one.php?productadded');
```

The photos are being saved in the file destination and so as the data in database. All the details are displaying except the image.

Comment: Solution to my/this problem: <img src='uploads/".$row['image']."  '/>

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the image data and send it out with the correct mime type, etc.

Here's what I do for file attachments to force a download

```
<?php

// gives me executeQuery which does pdo prepared query and returns an array
// where [0] is true or false, and [1] is either error message (if 0 false)
// or [1..N] are the rows returned from a select
include('PDO.inc.php');

$q="SELECT file_data, file_mime, file_size, file_name FROM fileStorage where pk=?";
$a=array(33);
$res=executeQuery($q,$a);
if(!$res[0]){
    print("<h2><font color=red>Error</font> ".$res[1]."</h2>");
    exit;
}

header("Content-length: ".$res[1]['file_size']);
header("Content-type: ".$res[1]['file_type']);
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$res[1]['file_name']);
echo $res[1]['file_data'];
?>
```

If you want to do something like embed images into a webpage and not force a "save as..." you can determine what image type based on stored mime type, and then use appropriate ImageMagick stuff like [imagecreatefrompng](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php)(), send an appropriate content header, and then send the image data itself with  [imagepng](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php)()

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your page source and looked to see what is being called by your code?

This looks suspect to me as you have the image result from the database query then the uploads/ tagged on the end which is outside the ' '

```
<div><img src='".$row['image']."' uploads/></div>
```

Should it be:

```
<div><img src='uploads/".$row['image']."'></div>
```

Comment: Yep, all are being called but the image still dont display. I even try ur code. It displays just a thumbnail corrupted

Comment: Post the line with the imgage tags.

Comment: Glad you have sorted it and It is always nice to edit your post so others with the same/similar problem who find this thread know how you did it.